# Unable to list folders when using scoped app permission for Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-sdk

I'm able to successfully list folder and contents when my dropbox developer app has full access, however, when I'm using scoped access only to a specific folder, it fails.

[image: successful request]

Now when I switch to scoped access to a specific folder I'm running into errors. This request should fail since the app does not have access to the folder.

[image: failure]

Now when I put in the right folder path, I'm still getting the same error.

[image]

For reference I'm sharing my app details
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the App Folder permission. This will root all your paths relative to that app folder; your app will not be able to see outside of it.

For example, if the user sees the file as "/Apps/AppFolderAccess/myfile.txt", your app will see it as "/myfile.txt".  By setting your path to /Apps/AppFolderAccess, it is effectively resolving as /Apps/AppFolderAccess/Apps/AppFolderAccess - which is not found.

If your application needs to see content outside its app folder, you should select full access.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of the other answer: you need to set the application permission to access type "Full Dropbox– Access to all files and folders in a user's Dropbox."

However, note that this requires you to delete your existing app and create a new one since it is not possible to change the scope of an existing app.